# Blade and the Negative case

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm sorry I do not know how to word this question. I'm new to Laravel and I want to either show a photo(s) or if there are no photos I want to show a placeholder. This works but there must be a better way to do it than this.

```
      @foreach ($items as $item)
      <?php $totalpics=0; ?>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
            @if(! empty($item->photos) )
              @foreach ( $item->photos as $photo )
                  @if ($photo->photo)
                      <a href="/storage/images/large/{{ $photo->photo }}"><img src="/storage/images/small/{{ $photo->photo }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ $item->name }}"></a>
                      <?php $totalpics++; ?>
                  @endif

              @endforeach

            @if(1 > $totalpics)
                      <a href="/items/{{ $item->id }}"><img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="{{ $item->name }}"></a>
            @endif
```

Comment: You should be able to get a count of the collection of photos by using $item->photos->count() if that helps.

Comment: Perfect! That works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want to achieve a for loop and an optional statement for when there is nothing to show in the for loop.

Laravel uses the `forelse` loop for this (see [all blade loops in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops)).

A basic `forelse` could be:

```
@forelse($items as $item)
  {{$item}}
@empty
  There are no items to display
@endforelse
```

*Above code is pseudo code and would not actually run*
Which would render as either all the `items` or as the text `There are no items to display`.

In your case you could use:

```
@forelse($items as $item)
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      @forelse ( $item->photos as $photo )
        @if ($photo->photo)
          <a href="/storage/images/large/{{ $photo->photo }}">
            <img src="/storage/images/small/{{ $photo->photo }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ $item->name }}">
          </a>
        @endif
      @empty
        <a href="/items/{{ $item->id }}">
          <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="{{ $item->name }}">
        </a>
      @endforelse
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Side note, this will not render any photos if there is a `photo` model attached to your `item` but the `photo` model does not have the `photo` property set, i.e. the `for` loop will be used but the `if` statement will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
@foreach ($items as $item)

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        @unless($item->photos)

            <a href="/items/{{ $item->id }}"><img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="{{ $item->name }}"></a>

        @else

          @foreach ( $item->photos as $photo )
              @if ($photo->photo)
                  <a href="/storage/images/large/{{ $photo->photo }}"><img src="/storage/images/small/{{ $photo->photo }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ $item->name }}"></a>
              @endif
          @endforeach

        @endunless
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is the kind of thing I was trying to begin with but wasn't working for me. In Laravel 5.4 your code does not work for me. Sorry for not stating the Laravel version in the question. Changing my last `if` statement to `@if(1 > $item->photos->count())` in my question meant that I could remove the PHP.

Comment: I will review the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do that in laravel 5.3+ by using

```
    @forelse($item->photos as $photo)
       <a href="/storage/images/large/{{ $photo->photo }}"><img src="/storage/images/small/{{ $photo->photo }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ $item->name }}"></a>
    @empty
      <a href="/items/{{ $item->id }}"><img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="{{ $item->name }}"></a>
   @endforelse
```